# Symfony2: How to extend DoctrineBahaviors?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) extension in my Symfony 3.0 project. Due to [this change](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) I have to override the [UserCallable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/ORM/Blameable/UserCallable.php) class. Is it possible to do this with [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) or any other way?

In more detail I want to override the original method:

```
class UserCallable {
    ...
    public function __invoke() {
        $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
        if (null !== $token) {
            return $token->getUser();
        }
    }
}
```

probably in my custom bundle class:

```
class MyUserCallable extends UserCallable {
    ...
    public function __invoke() {
        $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        if (null !== $token) {
            return $token->getUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The latest UserCallable class from DoctrineBehaviors correctly accesses `security.token_storage`

Comment: if you ever see a bundle thats out of date with the framework, raise an friendly issue with the author on github.  It might be that theyve overlooked it, you might even be able to put in a PR to fix it.

Comment: You both are right. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jason Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307183/jason-roman) said, upgrading from 1.1 to 1.3 solved the issue.

In case of standard extensions (e.g. adding publishedAt, publishedBy like in [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions)) - [using traits](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/198) should do the trick.